# Writing to log causes App to crash?

Tags: android

I was going through following tutorial: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/#viewSource

Inside the `FileChooser` class there is one exception beeing supressed, since there is nothing within the catch clause. So I decided to add following statement to the catch clause:

```
Log.e(ACTIVITY_SERVICE, e.getCause().toString());
```

For some reason this always causes the app to crash (NullPointerException). When I don't do any logging, except for a a simple syso print, then I don't get any exception and the app does't crash either. Then it works fine. I'm new to the whole Android Framework and just want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: what if your getCause() returns null?

Comment: even if it did, this wouldn't explain why there is an exception thrown in the first place. I can add some random syso with some hardcoded string and then I don't get any exception and there is no output on the console.

Comment: Use `Log.e(ACTIVITY_SERVICE, "Something meaningful", e);`, please. "there is no output on the console" -- there is not supposed to be. Android logs are viewed via LogCat.

Comment: Unless you define `Log` weirdly, either `e` being `null` or `e.getCause()`  being `null` is the only reason for a NPE in that line. The last one is the most likely. However, it'd be best to just log `e` anyway, not its cause or anything. /edit: Just as CommonsWare just wrote.

Comment: I did not initialize Log, since i was using a static method. When I do what CommonsWare said, I still get a NPE, but the app doesn't crash anymore. It's like an empty exception is being thrown...

Comment: Since you know that it's a NPE, you must have some kind of log output or stacktrace. Could you just share that with us?

Comment: the catch block contains following: 
System.out.println(e.toString());
System.out.println("ERROR!");
Log.e(ACTIVITY_SERVICE, "Something meaningful", e);

the output is following:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0ZVIOwaboQjNVVPQ1RCQm5KeEE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: All I can see from that is that your `catch` block successfully caught a NullPointerException inside the `try` block. What makes you think the NPE is caused within the `catch` block? What is line `38` in `FileBrowser.java`?

Comment: aww, man! I was totally wrong! I didn't notice the syso prints! they where there all the time! Line 38 points to the for loop which iterates on the files within the directory, so this is propably the point where the exception is being caused. As I said, I'm not used to the Framework and thus not to those log messages, I thought the java syso is being printed to the java console instead of the log. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: We all have those days :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ingo's and CommonsWare's hints I came to the conclusion, that following line caused the exception:

EDIT:

In fact it was the start of the foreach loop, which iterates over all subdirectories and files of a given directory. I didn't know, that this would cause a NPE, if the list you want to iterate on is actually null. For some reason I thought that the loop would be automatically skipped in this case.